# what is the root cause of UCF error in Documentum?

Tags: documentum, webtop

I see a lot often the following error when trying to access Documentum using webtop.

[image: UCF error]

Renaming/deleting the ucf folder under C:/Users//Documentum resolves this issue, however the issue comes more often.

I would like to know what is the reason it occurs this frequent. What exactly cause this and how can it be resolved permanently.